# fit more than one lognormal data with python

Tags: python, mathematical-optimization, curve-fitting

I am not high proficiency at maths, what i'm trying to do is to fit several populations that are supposed to be lognormal distributed. My piece of code is the next:

```
from scipy.optimize import curve_fit

# Generation of 3 population:
import numpy as np

s1 = np.random.lognormal(2, 0.6, 1000)  #mu and sigma
s2 = np.random.lognormal(1.6, 0.3, 1000) #mu and sigma
s3 = np.random.lognormal(1.8, 0.5, 1000) #mu and sigma

mb = np.max([s1,s2,s3])
X = np.arange(1,mb,1)
 #histogram population 1
Y11, bins1 = np.histogram(s1, X)
Y1 = Y11/Y11.sum()
X1 = bins1[:-1]

 #histogram population 2
Y22, bins2 = np.histogram(s2, X)
Y2 = Y22/Y22.sum()
X2 = bins2[:-1]

 #histogram population 3
Y33, bins3 = np.histogram(s3, X)
Y3 = Y33/Y33.sum()
X3 = bins3[:-1]

 #universe, with all mixed populations
S =  np.concatenate((s1, s2, s3), axis=None)


Yi, bins = np.histogram(S, X)
Y = Yi/Yi.sum()
X = bins[:-1]

def logN(x, mu, sigma):
      
    return  (np.exp(-(np.log(x) - mu)**2 / (2 * sigma **2)) / (x * sigma * np.sqrt(2 * np.pi)))  #lognormal function

params, pcov = curve_fit(logN, X,Y, method="lm")
print(params)
plt.plot(X1, Y1, 'o')
plt.plot(X2, Y2, 'o')
plt.plot(X3, Y3, 'o')
plt.plot(X, Y, 'r-o')
plt.plot(X, logN(X ,params[0], params[1])) 

plt.show()
```

This code produces a graph where I can get the global parameters mu and sigma. However, I'm confusing how should I do to get back the parameters of each population from the mixed population data. Any idea how to handle this problem is welcome

[image]

Comment: Why not just do `curve_fit(logN, X1,Y1, method="lm"), curve_fit(logN, X2,Y2, method="lm")`... ? Like you want the log params of each of the three populations?

Comment: same question, why can't you fit each population separately?

Comment: I'm sorry I wasn't clear. The main problem starts with only the mixed population. That's mean that I only have 'S' and my desired output is to get 'mu' for each possible population that compounds 'S'

Comment: You have a sample that you assume is a mixture of three log-normal distributions, and you want to estimate best-fit mu and sigma for the three component distributions?  Do you assume the three components each make up a third of the overall sample?

Comment: That's exactly the problem

Comment: I'm pretty sure I read some accessible stuff on Wikipedia recently about mixture distributions, and there might be something specifically on mixtures of log-normals.  Then off the top of my head it sounds like looking for a regression model with 6 parameters (3 mu and 3 sigma) that minimises squared deviation from your data or some other loss function...  Obviously not a solution, but maybe vaguely helpful?